# Is a Java foreach loop over an immutable volatile array thread-safe?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, volatile

I have a volatile reference to an immutable array that is changed asynchronously by replacing the reference with a new version.
Is it guaranteed to be thread-safe when iterating with foreach over this array?

Example:

```
class MyClass
{ 
  volatile String[] m_array = new String[0];

  public synchronized void add(String n)
  { m_array = ArrayUtils.add(m_array, n); // atomic replace
  }

  public void iterate() // not synchronized!
  { // Do something with each element
    for (String s : m_array)
      System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

**Why I ask this Question?**

Normally the foreach loop in Java expands to an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<String> i = m_array.iterator();
while(i.hasNext())
  ...
```

In this case there is *only one access* to m_array effectively taking an atomic snapshot. So everything is fine.

But what if a future Java implementation *optimizes* foreach for raw arrays because iterators are quite slow in this case?
(see [foreach vs. for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work))

The implementation might generate code like

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_array.length; i++)
{ String s = m_array[i];
  ...
```

This is no longer thread-safe, because of multiple accesses to `m_array`.
In this case a temporary variable with a snapshot of `m_array` is required when the field is volatile.

Is the above optimization guaranteed never to happen in this way and my code example guaranteed to be safe?

Comment: You say "only one access to m_array". What do you think the iterator does? It accesses m_array during the entire loop. An optimization that accesses the raw array directly would not be much different.

Comment: As a side note, Java has a List type that works like you'd think: [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: @Rudi Velthuis
No, the iterator does not access `m_array` at all. It only accesses the array *referenced by* `m_array`. This is safe because the latter is immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, using an enhanced for loop on a volatile array reference is thread-safe** with respect to asynchronous changes of the volatile field.

#### Rationale

> But what if a future Java implementation optimizes foreach for raw arrays because iterators are quite slow in this case?

`Iterator`s are not used for enhanced for loops for arrays, only for `Iterable`s. The Java Language Specification guarantees that every array access within the loop is on the same instance for every iteration, even if the value of `m_array` has changed during the iteration. An enhanced for loop for an array is specified using the following equivalent code:

```
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```

See [14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html). The key point here is that `Expression`, in your case `this.m_array`, *is only evaluated once*.

It is important to stress that the iteration uses a reference to the array, not a copy of it, so it is possible that the elements in the array could change during the iteration. However I assume from your code example that you know this can't happen.